# pycharmの左ペイン部の赤枠で囲った部分がイエローハイライトの意味

Tags: python3, pycharm

画像、赤枠内がイエローハイライトなんですが、これってどんな意味でしょうか？

pycharmの知識が少なくお分かりの方がいましたらご教示願います。

[image: pycharm左ペイン部イエローハイライト]

Comment: External Librariesの下なので対象では無いかもしれませんが、この辺の記事で解説されている内容が関連しているかもしれませんね。[プロジェクトツールウィンドウ](https://pleiades.io/help/pycharm/project-tool-window.html), [ファイルステータスのハイライト](https://pleiades.io/help/pycharm/file-status-highlights.html) 色のコードや設定ファイル等で調べてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: ちなみにありそうなのが「無視　ファイルは VCS によって意図的に追跡されていません。」ではないでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
まだ、知識不足なので頂いたコメントを元に調べて理解していきます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External LibrariesはPyCharmがPythonの設定をもとに自動的に認識したライブラリ類です。
表示はされていますが、現在のプロジェクトの管理外で、そのためハイライトされています。
このエリアの書き換えようとすると警告が表示されると思います（強行はできます）。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
現在のプロジェクトの管理外ということは、ライブラリー等も使えないということで認識あってますか？
実は、pycharmでライブラリーをimportしても、グレーアウトされ反映されずに困ってまして。。

Comment: 管理外と書いたのは、自分で追加削除するものではなくPyCharmが認識したものという意味です。